# How to write Bengali font in The Legrand Orange Book Template (English)

Tags: xetex, books

I would like to use

```
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Siyam Rupali, feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla}
```

to write Bengali font in [The Legrand Orange Book Template (English)](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book.).

here is the code in the main file, I have used :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.4 (26/09/2018)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Compiling this template:
% This template uses biber for its bibliography and makeindex for its index.
% When you first open the template, compile it from the command line with the 
% commands below to make sure your LaTeX distribution is configured correctly:
%
% 1) pdflatex main
% 2) makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist
% 3) biber main
% 4) pdflatex main x 2
%
% After this, when you wish to update the bibliography/index use the appropriate
% command above and make sure to compile with pdflatex several times 
% afterwards to propagate your changes to the document.
%
% This template also uses a number of packages which may need to be
% updated to the newest versions for the template to compile. It is strongly
% recommended you update your LaTeX distribution if you have any
% compilation errors.
%
% Important note:
% Chapter heading images should have a 2:1 width:height ratio,
% e.g. 920px width and 460px height.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations




\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Siyam Rupali, feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla} % to write bengali in latex


\input{structure.tex} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

%\hypersetup{pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}} % Uncomment and fill out to include PDF metadata for the author and title of the book

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty} % Suppress headers and footers on the title page
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background.pdf}};
\draw (current page.center) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering The Search for a Title\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large A Profound Subtitle}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\huge Dr. John Smith}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2019 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information, replace this with your own license (if any)

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2019} % Printing/edition date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers for the following pages

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right side of the book

\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable headers and footers again

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part One}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Text Chapter}

\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}

\lipsum[1-7] % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Citation}\index{Citation}

This statement requires citation \cite{article_key}; this one is more specific \cite[162]{book_key}.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Lists}\index{Lists}

Lists are useful to present information in a concise and/or ordered way\footnote{Footnote example...}.

\subsection{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}

\begin{itemize}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\begin{description}
\item[Name] Description
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Comment] Elaboration
\end{description}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}

This is an example of theorems.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
This is a theorem consisting of several equations.

\begin{theorem}[Name of the theorem]
In $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ all norms are equivalent. It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
This is a theorem consisting of just one line.

\begin{theorem}
A set $\mathcal{D}(G)$ in dense in $L^2(G)$, $|\cdot|_0$. 
\end{theorem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}

This is an example of a definition. A definition could be mathematical or it could define a concept.

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
Given a vector space $E$, a norm on $E$ is an application, denoted $||\cdot||$, $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty[$ such that:
\begin{align}
& ||\mathbf{x}||=0\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\\
& ||\lambda \mathbf{x}||=|\lambda|\cdot ||\mathbf{x}||\\
& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||\leq ||\mathbf{x}||+||\mathbf{y}||
\end{align}
\end{definition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Notations}\index{Notations}

\begin{notation}
Given an open subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of functions $\varphi$ are:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bounded support $G$;
\item Infinitely differentiable;
\end{enumerate}
a vector space is denoted by $\mathcal{D}(G)$. 
\end{notation}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}

This is an example of a remark.

\begin{remark}
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{remark}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}

This is an example of a corollary.

\begin{corollary}[Corollary name]
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{corollary}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}

This is an example of propositions.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}

\begin{proposition}[Proposition name]
It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $f,g\in L^2(G)$; if $\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{D}(G)$, $(f,\varphi)_0=(g,\varphi)_0$ then $f = g$. 
\end{proposition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Examples}\index{Examples}

This is an example of examples.

\subsection{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}

\begin{example}
Let $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<3\}$ and denoted by: $x^0=(1,1)$; consider the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned} & \mathrm{e}^{|x|} & & \text{si $|x-x^0|\leq 1/2$}\\
& 0 & & \text{si $|x-x^0|> 1/2$}\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
The function $f$ has bounded support, we can take $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x-x^0|\leq 1/2+\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon\in\intoo{0}{5/2-\sqrt{2}}$.
\end{example}

\subsection{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}

\begin{example}[Example name]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}

This is an example of an exercise.

\begin{exercise}
This is a good place to ask a question to test learning progress or further cement ideas into students' minds.
\end{exercise}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Problems}\index{Problems}

\begin{problem}
What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
\end{problem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

Define a word to improve a students' vocabulary.

\begin{vocabulary}[Word]
Definition of word.
\end{vocabulary}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part Two}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 3
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Presenting Information}

\section{Table}\index{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\label{tab:example} % Unique label used for referencing the table in-text
%\addcontentsline{toc}{table}{Table \ref{tab:example}} % Uncomment to add the table to the table of contents
\end{table}

Referencing Table \ref{tab:example} in-text automatically.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{placeholder.jpg}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig:placeholder} % Unique label used for referencing the figure in-text
%\addcontentsline{toc}{figure}{Figure \ref{fig:placeholder}} % Uncomment to add the figure to the table of contents
\end{figure}

Referencing Figure \ref{fig:placeholder} in-text automatically.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}} % Add a Bibliography heading to the table of contents

%------------------------------------------------

\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]

%------------------------------------------------

\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage % Make sure the index starts on an odd (right side) page
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm} % Space between the 2 columns of the index
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}} % Add an Index heading to the table of contents
\printindex % Output the index

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it gives errors. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: _[Disclaimer & Disclosure: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ If you're compiling this on Overleaf, Kalpurush and Siyam Rupali are not installed on OL. You can use other available fonts as listed on https://bit.ly/2XyNNaF. You would probably need to remove `\usepackage[english]{babel}` in that `structure.tex`, and also add `\newfontfamily{\bengalifontsf}[Script=Bengali]{Noto Sans Bengali}` if your project contains any `\textsf{...}` or `\sffamily`.

Comment: @ LianTzeLi I have compiled it on local mecine, MacBook Air. Without "latexbangla" package  everything is fine, but gives errors when I use "latexbangla". All the necessary Bengali fonts are installed on my MacOS.

Comment: @ LianTzeLi According to your instruction I have done the process and finally my problem is solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have all required fonts installed on your machine: The `latexbangla` package uses `polyglossia`, which may conflict with `babel`. So you would also need to look in your preamble (including `structure.tex`) to see if there's a `\usepackage[...]{babel}`, and remove it. `latexbangla` seems to have been written with English and Bengali in mind, so if these are the languages you want to work in anyway, you shouldn't need to add extra language options.

`latexbangla` has package options to set the "serif" font and the "teletype" font, but none for setting the "sans serif" font. If you have any `\sffamily` or `\textsf{...}` in your project, you would then likely get a `The current latin font bttfont does not contain the "Bengali" script!` error.

Therefore you may also need to add in your preamble

```
\newfontfamily{\bengalifontsf}[Script=Bengali]{Noto Sans Bengali}
%% or some other suitable font available on your machine
```